# Is there a nation in the history who has valued hypocrisy?

Tags: ethics

The more I search about hypocrisy, the more I see that it's something that is detested by the masses.

I wonder if there is anytime or anywhere in the world or during history that a nation valued hypocrisy, advised for it, cherished it, saw it as a morally and ethically good thing, and preached it?

Comment: I do not think that you can find a "society" liking it... but you can find reference to Renaissance Europe: [Nicodemite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicodemite).

Comment: Extensive hypocrisy and lying even if it is not grave (eg covering up criminal behavior) is still detrimental as it gradually creates extensive mistrust and suspiciousness thus nullifying social unity. It is no wonder no society (openly) supports such behavior

Comment: What do you call "hypocrisy" and "value"? If hypocrisy is talking nice to people we despise or don't care about, it's the bread and butter of sociability since time immemorial. Seduction, career advancement, business deals, elections are based on it (or at least much facilitated). In that sense it could be said that it's been valued forever. People claim to not like it but I also observe they tend to dislike people who speak their mind too much even more...

Comment: @armand, you confuse kindness with hypocrisy. It is not the same, one is being kind as a disposition of character regardless of  type of relation to another. You should be at least very sceptical of politicians that pretend to care for you.

Comment: @NikosM. I explicitly said "talking nice to people we despise". How is that kind in anyway? I could have understood if you said "politeness", but that's the point: the difference between politeness and hypocrisy is about the same as between a "terrorist" and a "freedom fighter", hence my comment that OP should define their terms if they expect an helpful answer.

Comment: There is a a blurred line of demarcation between hypocrisy and [taqiyyah](https://www.britannica.com/topic/taqiyyah) in Islamist ideology. It is a much discussed ethical issue in Islamic theology.

Comment: @TankutBeygu when it is clear that your behavior is the result of force and coercion (eg threat of death or injury) and it is clear that you conform against your will, it cannot be called deception nor lying. In other words, when it is clear and known that one pretends, it ceases to produce the results that pretending successfully would produce. Thus cannot be called pretending any more.

Comment: @armand, being nice to people we despise because we honestly hold the view that such behavior is the best even in such cases is not deception nor lying. We act honestly.

Comment: @NikosM. leading people to  false belief about our feelings is precisely deception and lying. Wether we have a valid reason to deceive them is another matter. And if we honestly tell people "I despise you but how are you today?", we can hardly call that being polite. That's why you can't trace a net line between what is polite behavior and what is hypocrisy. And it has clearly nothing to do with kindness.

Comment: @armand, this is the crucial difference. If we are asked "what do you think of me" and answer "I think you are the best" but we despise the person. Then we deceive. If we answer "i dont have the best opinion but that is no reason to not be civil" then we don't deceive. Hope this is clear now.

Comment: @armand in other words (let's agree on civil behavior) if I display civil behavior is independent of deception per se. Which is exactly what sociality needs.

Comment: @armand as for faking one·s feelings and pretending, i seriously doubt this can go on for a long time, in most cases not even for an instant. We don't really need this socially

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that is just marketing.

We might call the same behaviour stubborn, or determined.

One persons hypocrisy, is another's ‘pragmatic flexibility in the encounter with realpolitik’, say.

> “Never attempt to win by force what can be won by deception.”
>
> “A man who is used to acting in one way never changes; he must come to
> ruin when the times, in changing, no longer are in harmony with his
> ways.”
>
> -Machiavelli, in The Prince

I would describe Machiavelli as having basically game—theory derived ethics, and in that context his judgements turn on what works, and how people behave in practice.

We more usually in philosophy deal with intersubjective-derived ethics, about universalising personal rules, like Kant’s Imperative or Rawl’s theory of justice.

It’s important to consider context. Say you are in a war against desperate opposition, saying someone trying to shoot you is also a hypocrite, not useful. And keeping standards of honesty and consistency when lives are on the line, may look morally unjustifiable to those people. You could argue satisfying your conscience is a luxury weighed against heavy consequences. The British were extremely deceptive in WW2, indeed they had earned the nickname [Perfidious Albion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfidious_Albion) already back during the French Revolution. By contrast, almost no German-born spies operated in WW2, they had to use foreign nationals.

In practice there is a tension between these systems. Often more concern for family members, isn’t written into ethical theories. It’s a game-theory product, from natural selection. Kant wrote [On a Supposed Right to Tell Lies from Benevolent Motives](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_a_Supposed_Right_to_Tell_Lies_from_Benevolent_Motives), and I think it’s fair to say the overwhelming majority of philosophers and others consider it an unjustifiably extreme stance. The converse, is that very few would genuinely follow Machiavelli’s advice, or celebrate those that do even if they are successful.

Comment: Some say a lie can be as grave as a murder, because it can be used to cover it up. In less grave cases then there is no reason anyway. I tend to agree with the stance of zero hypocrisy

Comment: @NikosM.: As in, lying is never moral, like Kant?

Comment: Kant·s thesis is close to my heart. I have not found a case so far where approaches other than deception cannot achieve same or better results (assuming good results)

Comment: Radical honesty would be the admission that dishonesty is ubiquitous.

Comment: @Meanach: Tell me the bitter truth? We are all rascals. Tell me the sweet lie? We wish we weren't.

Comment: Yes. He who says that he is not a liar is a liar. Seriously, the ability to lie is an obvious survival trait.  No honest human survived.

Comment: i don't lie @Meanach i cannot remember the last one, anyway, and not due to fatuousness. it debases every claim someone makes, and implies consent to being tricked if it is to be expected.

Comment: You are a rare breed. Some lies are more important than others. If answering the question "Are you a Jew?" with yes will result in death, then a lie is justified in the interest of survival.  If answering the question "Do you like my haircut?" with no  will result in hurt feelings, then a lie is justified in the interest of compassion. The first question is an invasion of privacy, so there is no obligation to give an honest answer. The second question is a matter of opinion, so there is no objective truth. Stating that people should tell the truth at all times is unrealistic and illiberal.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that most individuals value harmony over truth. A soft lie is preferable to a hard truth. As to hypocrisy and lies, it is abundant in politics, advertising, and diplomacy. So our current society values hypocrisy privately and condemns it publicly. More hypocrisy. The Prince by Machiavelli is a ruthlessly honest work. I would also recommend The Inferno by Dante for attitudes to hypocrisy.